# python rounds automatically when i work trhough spyder, but not when i type in direcly in console =S

Tags: python, rounding, spyder

so i am making a class of employess, and i want to make a function that returns total time worked

try
1, running this through spyder
2. running it in console

gives different results :S

```
class Employee(object):      
    def __init__(self, wage, wage1, hours_accounting=[]):
        self.wage=wage
        self.wage1=wage1
        self.hours_accounting=hours_accounting
    def work(self):               
        A=H,M=input('when did you start work today? format hh,mm')
        B=H1,M1=input('when did you stop work today? format hh,mm')     
        total_time_in_hours=H1-H + (M1-M)/60              
        return total_time_in_hours

amanda=Employee(100, 50)
amanda.work()
07,15
21,00
```

#

why?? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder dev here*) Before Spyder `2.3.0` we ran this code while starting a console:

```
from __future__ import division
```

which makes things like `2/3` to return `0.6666` instead of `0` (which is the normal behavior in Python 2).

To change this you have three options:

1. Update to `2.3.0`
2. If you are using a *Python* Console, you need to go to

   `Preferences > Console > Advanced Settings > PYTHONSTARTUP replacement`

   and select the option called

   `Default PYTHONSTARTUP script`.
3. If you are using the IPython console, you need to go to

   `Preferences > IPython Console > Graphics`

   and deselect the option called

   `Automatically load Pylab and NumPy modules`

Comment: You should not disable true division if it is active since that is the Python 3.0 behavior and it is best to prepare code today for an eventual transition. Just use truncating division "//" explicitly and you'll get the old behavior in a portable way.

Comment: We deactivated it because of the confusion it generated in newbies (like the one reported by the OP): "it works one way in Python but in Spyder it works differently". IMHO the really portable way of doing this is to call `from __future__ import division` explicitly, not for us to force it to our users =)